# Should making two calls to window.onload be valid?

Tags: javascript

I have two blocks of JavaScript which both call functions via `winodow.onload`.  One of the functions is called on every page, but the other is only called on one specific page.  On that page one function works, but the other does not, and I am not getting any errors that I can see.

Does it matter that both functions are called via `window.onload` in different script blocks (see example)?  Shouldn't this work?

```
<!--some html-->

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function firstFunction(){
        //do stuff
    }
    window.onload = firstFunction;
</script>

<!--some html-->

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function secondFunction(){
        //do stuff
    }
    window.onload = secondFunction;
</script>

<!--some html-->
```

**UPDATE:**

I ended up taking zzzzBov's suggestion of using jQuery's `$(document).ready(doAction);` function.  Now I have multiple`.js` included on a single page all using this call and there is no conflict.

Comment: why does the javascript have to be in two blocks?

Comment: Once you start getting deeper into modular JavaScript you'll quickly realize it'd be nice to reuse chunks of code in an easier manner. While I don't want to advocate *always-using-a-library-for-everything-even-when-it's-not-necessary* I highly recommend jQuery for just this sort of thing.

Comment: If you want to add multiple event listeners, have a look at: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: @errorhandler the way the site is set up each page is divided into several `.cfm` files, each of which represents a certain section of the page. If I want something to appear in the section where `component1.cfm` is located, I must put my code there. Originally I divided up my scripts in the `.cfm` files they related to, but now I have enough scripts that it might be easier to lump them all into one `.js` file and sort it out there.

Comment: @zzzzBov I have never got around to using jQuery since most of the scripts I have to write are pretty small, but I plan on using it in my next project. Do you think it is worth using when I have less than 100 line of code in all of the JavaScript across my department's site?

Comment: @typoknig, first off, i like your name, and secondly, it's worth knowing as it *significantly* reduces the amount of code that's needed to do advanced things. I replaced a buggy 10-year old script of 2k+ lines of JS with 20 lines of jQuery, 10 of which were comments. For simple value checking and variable manipulation, jQuery is unnecessary, but for dom-manipulation and event handling, jQuery is *awesome*.

Comment: @typoknig, also, the jQuery solution to the onload event is `jQuery(function($){...your code here...});`, you can call that as many times as you need and all will work.

Comment: @zzzzBov thanks for telling me about the jQuery equivalent of `window.onload`. Our organization include jQuery in all of our pages, so that simple call worked great for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking zzzzBov's suggestion of using jQuery's $(document).ready(doAction); function. Now I have multiple.js included on a single page all using this call and there is no conflict.

Answer (score 15):

The recommended best practice for registering event handlers is to use "addEventListener" (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). Using this method ensures that the handler is additive and does not replace existing handlers.

```
function something() {alert("1");}
function somethingElse() {alert("2");}

window.addEventListener("load", something, false);
window.addEventListener("load", somethingElse, false);
```

Comment: You should mention that IE uses different methods for that.

Comment: @Felix, thanks for pointing that out. IE uses "attachEvent" see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This solved my problem as well.   I was trying to use window.onload and that conflicted with Primefaces/JSF.

Answer (score 5):

The second `onload` assignment is erasing the first. So if you have two `window.onload` assignments on the same page pointing to two different handlers the second will win. You will need to merge them into a single one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function firstFunction(){
        //do stuff
    }
</script>

<!--some html-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function secondFunction(){
        //do stuff
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        firstFunction();
        secondFunction();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: sigh, that is what I figured, I was just hoping I was wrong :(

Answer (score 3):

As @Darin said, the second assignment is overwriting the first value assigned to `onload`. Check out [Simon Willison's general purpose](http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/) approach to creating multiple `onload` events:

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}
```

Used like this:

```
addLoadEvent(nameOfSomeFunctionToRunOnPageLoad);
addLoadEvent(function() {
  /* more code to run on page load */ 
});
```

I'll let him explain it:

> The way this works is relatively
>   simple: if window.onload has not
>   already been assigned a function, the
>   function passed to addLoadEvent is
>   simply assigned to window.onload. If
>   window.onload has already been set, a
>   brand new function is created which
>   first calls the original onload
>   handler, then calls the new handler
>   afterwards.

Closures are pretty cool.

Comment: @Iwburk this sounds good, I'm going to look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Simple. Try this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
    alert("hello 1");
});
  
window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
    alert("hello 2");
});
  
window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
    alert("hello 3");
});
```

}